# How can I know if a Date is Saturday?

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date as string on client side :

```
var myDate = "08/08/2012";
```

how can I know if this date is Saturday or not?

Comment: helping link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `while (today !== date) sleep(); if (!me.atWork()) isSaturday = true;` ;)

Comment: Can tell you're not self-employed @deceze ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn that string into a javascript date and use the [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function which will return a number from 0-6 (Sunday being 0, Monday 1 etc).

For the first part of that, you should split up your string and construct a `Date` object (Im not sure if your date is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy and the same will happen on client computers so be specific). The easiest way by far is to use a library such as [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) which would allow you to use code such as

```
var date = Date.parseExact("8/8/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy");
var isSaturday = (date.getDay() == 6);
```

One better than that, datejs has some extensions which can make this a one liner:

```
var isSaturday = Date.parseExact("8/8/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy").is().saturday();
```

Comment: What about this? `var dateArrivoParts = valArrivoHome.split("/");
                var dateArrivo = new Date(dateArrivoParts[2], (dateArrivoParts[1] - 1), dateArrivoParts[0]);` this should works everywhere, right?

Comment: @markzzz - yes, that is a way to construct a date from a string, and will work fine, but I still think datejs is much better!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var myDate = new Date("08/08/2012");
console.log(myDate.getDay()); // if 0 then its Sunday
```

Comment: depending on the locale of the client machine that first line will or wont work.

Comment: So Jamiec : what's your solution?

Comment: I'm here with @Jamiec. I would use date.js library

Comment: @markzzz - you can look up the billion or so questions on changing a string to a date on SO, or wait a few mins and i'll update my answer for you

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the Open Source [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library for general date handling.

Using the library...

```
var dt = Date.parse(yourDateVariable);
if(Date.today().is().saturday()){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Date class has a function called getDay() which returns a integer between 0 and 6 (0 being Sunday, 6 being Saturday).

```
var today = new Date("08/08/2012");
if(today.getDay() == 6 ) alert('Saturday!');
```